# Windows 7 - Yeoman generator (gulp-angular) not finding/creating directory: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\dev\tty'

Tags: windows-7, yeoman, yeoman-generator

On a **fresh, global** install of yeoman, gulp, bower and generator-gulp-angular, I'm getting the following error:

```
$ yo gulp-angular

fs.js:439
    return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\dev\tty'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\ttys\index.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\baseUI.js:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

When I drill down to the **tty\index.js** file referenced in the error above, it *looks* like all that does is read a **/dev/tty** directory if it exists, or create it if it doesn't.

I'm basically just trying to create a dummy angular project with this generator, which is fairly popular. This is my first attempt at playing with Yeoman and generators but I've hit a wall right out of the gate.  Anyone have any ideas how to get the generator working?

I'm running **Windows 7** and the latest node/npm (updated them before doing the fresh installs above).

Answer (score 0):

this was an issue with a version on Inquirer.js - the version has been unpublished a while ago.

Just update your packages version: `npm -g update yo` - you can also uninstall and re-install. Whatever works for you.

Also, note that if you use a npm registry clone, I found out some of them do not get delete updates, so the broke version may still be available on your clone. Make sure you're correctly cloning npm :)